# Sorting a vector alongside another vector in C++

Tags: c++, sorting

I am writing a function in C++ which will take in 2 vectors of doubles called xvalues and yvalues.  My aim is to create an interpolation with these inputs.  However, it would be really convenient if the (x,y) pairs were sorted so that the x-values were in increasing order and the y-values still corresponded to the correct x-value.

Does anyone know how I can do this efficiently?

Comment: Is there a way to get only one vector of pairs, ie. (x,y)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you use a vector of pairs, which you then can sort easily with the [stl sort algorithm](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/), or you write your own sort method. Therefore you've [several options](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Summaries_of_popular_sorting_algorithms).
Within your own sorting algorithm you can then take care of not only sorting your x-vector but also the y-vector respectively.

Here as an example using bubble sort for your two vectors (`vec1` and `vec2`).

```
bool bDone = false;
while (!done) {
    done = true;
    for(unsigned int i=0; i<=vec1.size()-1; ++i) {
        if ( vec1.at(i) > vec1.at(i+1) ) {
            double tmp   = vec1.at(i);
            vec1.at(i)   = vec1.at(i+1);
            vec1.at(i+1) = tmp;
            tmp          = vec2.at(i);
            vec2.at(i)   = vec2.at(i+1);
            vec2.at(i+1) = tmp;
            done = false;
        }
    }
}
```

But again, as others pointed out here, you should defenitely use `std::vector< std::pair<double, double> >` and the just sort it.

Comment: Okay.  To sort a vector of pairs based on the first element of my pair, can I just use std::sort?

Answer (score 3):

I would probably create a vector of pairs and sort that by whatever means necessary.

It sounds like your data abstraction (2 separate collections for values that are actually "linked" is wrong).

Comment: My input must be 2 separate vectors.  My C++ program takes in the input values from Excel as 2 vectors.  Given these 2 vectors, should I just create a vector of pairs then?  How do you sort a vector of pairs into increasing order of the first element of the pair?

Comment: Whether it is wrong or not depends on the actual goal of his design. If he has to save memory, and can do that this way, then it is the right design.

Comment: @PlasmaHH: Last time I checked (STL, VC++2008), the std::pair's size (if we ignore alignment issues, which we can here because the types are both doubles) is exactly the same than the size of its components. Thus, I fail to see how two vectors of doubles could save memory when compared with one vector of pair of doubles... :-/

Comment: @paercebal He probably meant that at some point you'd have 3 vectors -  2 vectors of doubles and one vector of pairs.

Comment: @jrok : If the alternative is to have 3 vectors, then yes, you're right, the vector of pairs is overkill. But nowhere we have any hint this extreme case was the one described by the question author. On the contrary, the question author settled both in the comment above, and the chosen answer, for the algorithm to sort a vector of pairs.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative, you could write some kind of iterator adaptor that internally holds two iterators and increases/decreases/assigns them simultaneously. They dereference to a special type that on swap, swaps the two values in both vectors, but on compare only compare one. This might be some work (extra swap,op<, class ), but when done as a template, and you need this more often, could pay out.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is easy: implement a sort algorithm (e.g. quicksort is easy, short an OK for most use cases - there are a lot implementations available: http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=445 ).

- Do the compare on your x-vector and
- do the swap on both vectors.

The sort method has to take both vectors a input, but that should be a minor issue.